# border colors change when applying border-radius to a zero-width element

Tags: css

I'm using `border-top` and `border-left` on a zero-width element to create a triangle.

```css
.triangle {
  border-top: solid 100px red;
  border-left: solid 100px blue;
  width: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}
.borderRadius { border-radius: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle borderRadius"></div>
```

However if a `border-radius` is applied to the element, the red border turns blue!! See JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3z3gqwts/

What is happening here? Is there a way to get a rounded-corner on my triangle?

Comment: "What is happening here?" Going to guess it's the Chrome bug of the day.

Comment: I have added an image that I got ... that shows that somehow the bug is bigger than expected.

Comment: @vals: What browser, version and platform? I see a solid blue rectangle on Chrome/Win 53.0.2785.143

Comment: @BoltClock Chrome Versión 53.0.2785.143 m on Windows 7 64 bit.  But after playing with the dev tools as I say, At the beginning I see also a solid blue rectangle.

Comment: @BoltClock I have added a video

Comment: @vals: Ah, I missed that part. Man. Can you say ["IE6"](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer.html)?

Comment: @vals your edits are showing different things from what I describe in my question, but they're interesting nonetheless. There's definitely some really weird behavior happening here.

Answer (score 1):

To get a rounded border on your triangle you might have to declare all borders:

```
div {
  border-top: solid 50px red;
  border-right: solid 50px red;
  border-left: solid 50px blue;
  border-bottom: solid 50px blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/pmagkapj/)